# Enable Virtualization in BIOS if my computer isn't giving me the option

Tags: bios

How would I enable Virtualization in BIOS if my computer isn't giving me the option to do so?

Thanks

Comment: sorry, you probably can't. it is likely that at least one critical hardware component is not present on the CPU or on the motherboard. without knowing your exact hardware we could not venture a guess. there is a minute possibility that your hardware supports virtualization extensions, and a firmware (bios) update can expose the option. that said though, the manufacturer would have to provide that firmware, so I recommend you contact their support desk to determine whether they have one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly you need to check if your computer supports virtualisation. You can do that at http://ark.intel.com/ (I'm assuming it's Intel, look for your CPU and check if the VT-X feature is present). Alternatively, you can download and run the [Microsoft® Hardware-Assisted Virtualization Detection Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=592#filelist).

If your computer does supports it, and you have checked **every** option in the BIOS, and your BIOS is the **latest** version (go to your manufacturer's website), then the only option is to [flash a BIOS](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/04/03/what-is-flashing-the-bios/). The most popular site would be https://www.bios-mods.com/. Look for your computer make and model + BIOS version and follow the instructions there. Unfortunately this is the only way since your manufacturer did not add the option to enable virtualisation in the BIOS.

I ran into the same situation too - I have an Acer laptop and in my BIOS there's no option to enable VT-X (along with many others). In the end the only option was to flash a BIOS which has the options unlocked, but I decided against it as it was too risky- **IT MAY BRICK YOUR COMPUTER AND RENDER IT UNUSABLE**.

In conclusion, unless you desperately need virtualisation enabled, it's better to leave it as it is. Some manufacturer's just don't include the option in the BIOS...

**EDIT**:

I just upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 8.1 Pro. When I was in Windows 7, VT-X was disabled and due to the lack of options in my BIOS, I couldn't use it. After upgrading, apparently VT-X was enabled (though the option still isn't in the BIOS) and now I can use the feature now! Yay! :)

Comment: Hi, can you please share how I can find on windows8.1 that virtualization/ vt-x is allowed or on?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem on an Acer Aspire e15. For some reason these computers don't have a virtualization option in the BIOS. One workaround is to turn off the Hyper-V and disable memory integrity.

To do this:

1. Open a Command prompt with administrative rights (Admin) and type:

   ```
   bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
   ```
2. Open Windows Security > Device Security > Core Isolation Details
3. Turn *Memory Integrity* off

After turning Memory Integrity off you should be prompted to restart your machine. I was trying to run Docker Toolbox and it worked after I followed those steps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. 
American MegaTrends... version 7/7/2016 BIOS; 
With Intel Core i5 M450. 
Windows 8.1

I have 
Enabled Hyper V 
  --> Rebooted 
    --> Then Disbaled Hyper V. 
      --> Rebooted.
        -->Entered BIOS at the Booting time.
VT-X option is now Visible. I have ENABLED it and proceeded.