# VT-x/AMD-V hardware acceleration is not available - Windows 7 VirtualBox

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtualization

I'm trying to run a Mavericks virtual machine on my Windows 7 PC using VirtualBox. However, every time I try to run it, it gives me the error message:

```
VT-x/AMD-V hardware acceleration is not available on your system. 
Certain guests (e.g. OS/2 and QNX) require this feature and will fail to boot without it.
```

If I press continue it doesn't let me boot it up. I've looked up my processor and confirmed that it supports AMD-V, and Coreinfo.exe seems to support this too.

```
AMD Phenom(tm) II X6 1045T Processor
AMD64 Family 16 Model 10 Stepping 0, AuthenticAMD
HTT         *   Multicore
HYPERVISOR  -   Hypervisor is present
VMX         -   Supports Intel hardware-assisted virtualization
SVM         *   Supports AMD hardware-assisted virtualization
X64         *   Supports 64-bit mode

SMX         -   Supports Intel trusted execution
SKINIT      *   Supports AMD SKINIT
```

Additionally, I don't think Hyper-V is installed, so I'm stumped/

Does anyone know what could fix this?

Comment: It supports it, but have you enabled it in BIOS?

Comment: I'll try it, but I thought that AMD should have it enabled by default?

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/822851/enable-virtualization-in-bios-if-my-computer-isnt-giving-me-the-option/822898#822898