# No virtualization option in bios options in hp envy 700 215 xt core i7 processor

Tags: virtual-machine, cpu, bios, virtualization, hyper-v

I ran this CoreInfo tool from Sysinterals: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc835722 and it says

- HYPERVISOR      -       Hypervisor is present
- VMX                  *       Supports Intel hardware-assisted virtualization
- EPT                   *       Supports Intel extended page tables (SLAT)

but when I press F10, there are no virtualization options to be found. 
I am trying to turn on Hyper-V and create vms on Oracle Virtual Box.

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You can't have Hyper-V turned on AND use VirtualBox, as they conflict. But if you're using VB, why enable Hyper-V at all?  Also, have you tried updating your BIOS to the latest version to see if additional options were added?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enable Virtualization in BIOS if my computer isn't giving me the option](http://superuser.com/questions/822851/enable-virtualization-in-bios-if-my-computer-isnt-giving-me-the-option)