# Can't find "Virtualization Technology VT-x" option in BIOS

Tags: bios, virtualization, sony-vaio, linux-kvm, vt-x

I want to use KVM but I can't find the "Virtualization Technology VT-x" option in my BIOS to enable it; although I checked that my processor supports VT-x and I also checked with the "kvm-ok" command (it said that it supports kvm acceleration but it needs to be enabled).

Note:
I have an old Sony Vaio laptop (VGN-CR354) with Intel Core 2 duo Processor T8100 with an Ubuntu Desktop LTS operating system.

So, is there any other way to enable VT-x ?!?!

Please help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Some older systems that have VT-x capable CPUs won't have BIOSes that allow it to be enabled.

VT-x capable CPUs have a setting that prevents virtualization from being used or enabled until next hardware reset, and this is set or left alone by a BIOS.  Only by changing the BIOS can you change this behavior.

I cannot find a source for this but I believe VT-x needs chipset support and that may not be present on some motherboards.  Since your system is an older system this may be why the BIOS disables it and does not allow it to be enabled.

Check [here](https://superuser.com/questions/822851/enable-virtualization-in-bios-if-my-computer-isnt-giving-me-the-option) - this Superuser answer talks about obtaining a modified BIOS, but that is risky as it can brick your system.